# Python terminal not building database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building a chat messenger with Python.

When I create the database automatically via `db.create_all()`, the following error comes:

```
>>> db.create_all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Praktikant2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 887, in create_all
    self._call_for_binds(bind_key, "create_all")
  File "C:\Users\Praktikant2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 858, in _call_for_binds
    engine = self.engines[key]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Praktikant2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 639, in engines
    app = current_app._get_current_object()  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Praktikant2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 508, in _get_current_object
    raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.
>>>
```

I have following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Message(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=True)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

@app.route("/")
def start_page():
    return "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you running this code as a script? The error message looks like you are executing individual statements from a Python shell.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is **force the context** of your app. After the conection and instantiation, add the following line:

**app.app_context().push()**

Your code will be:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.app_context().push()
```

Then, on the terminal:

```
1. Python (or Python3)
2. from app import app
3. from app import db
4. db.create_all()
```